# Need simple UI Code in R

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, shinyjs

I have never created any UI in R, so need your help to create simple UI in R which has two browse buttons and Run button.

I have written the code to extract the fields from PDF files and gives the standardized the output in an excel file.

file_name1: it should select the filename from the first browse option.
file_name2: it should select the filename from the second browse option.

After browsing, it has to Run the program and back end my R code should execute.
After successfully execution, it has to show the timestamp: execution time in seconds and the message stating that "Successfully Completed"

Below is the R Code for the same:
    #Fix the Working directory path:
     setwd("D:/PROJECTS/PDF_TO_EXCEL_DEMO/")

```
#Calling required Libraries
source("CODES/CALL_LIBRARIES_v1.R")

################## IMPORTANT STEP ########################
# User has to update the filename here                    

file_name1="SAMPLE2017"  #filename should take it from first browse option
file_name2="SAMPLE2018"  #filename should take it from second browse option
file_ext=".pdf"
file_path="INPUTS/"
report_path="OUTPUTS/"

##########################################################

#Calling Prorams
source("CODES/CALL_PROGRAMS_v1.R")

#Removing all temp files from R
closeAllConnections()

rm(list=ls())
```

[image: UI should looks like this-copied from other sources]

Comment: You don't mention shiny specifically in the question, but it you have tagged it as such. Does this mean you are looking specifically for a shiny solution? Have you started with any [shiny tutorials](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/)? Here exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: @MrFlick - I don't know how to get the UI as shown in pic, without shiny is it possible?